# Conditional Redirect with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site: blog.example.com.

I want `blog.example.com` to go to `example.com/news`

But I want `blog.example.com/tag/mytag` or `blog.example.com/category/mycategory` to go to `example.com/tag/mytag` or `example.com/category/mycategory`

So far I have my .htaccess like this but of course it doesnt work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/news/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in root .htaccess of `blog.example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```